# debugging map-struct generated source code

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, debugging, mapstruct

Hi all and thanks in advance,

I'm using `SprinBoot 2.2.8` and `MapStruct 1.3.0.Beta2` and everythings works fine. I just want to debug the generated `impl` classes (located inside `/target/generated-sources/annotations/[package]/mapper`).

I try to put a breakpoint inside one of these classes (.java) but `Eclipse`, pointing to that class says me **Resource not found, Edit source lookup path..**.

I have tried to give it the above path but doesn't work.

Can you help me??

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add the package root of the generated source files as a "Source" folder in the project.  Go to project properties, find the "Build Path" entry, click on the "Source" tab.  I can't tell from that path you specify what the package root directory is.